# Изменение даты в системе при помощи Python в Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, дата

Нужно чтобы при запуске программы менялась дата например на 17.01.2021, после этого запускался определенный exe'шник, а спустя 40 секунд дата менялась обратно. я представляю это так:

```
import time
import xxx (библиотека для работы с временем/изменения времени в системе)

(изменение даты)
os.system(...)
time.sleep(40)
(возвращение даты)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081310

Comment: windows или linux ?

Comment: @n1tr0xs windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел способ изменения даты. Код выглядит так:

```
import datetime
import win32api
    
tt = datetime.datetime.utcnow().time()
win32api.SetSystemTime(2021, 1, 0, 17, tt.hour, tt.minute, tt.second, tt.microsecond//1000)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import sys
import datetime

time_tuple = ( 2012, # Year
                  9, # Month
                  6, # Day
                  0, # Hour
                 38, # Minute
                  0, # Second
                  0, # Millisecond
              )

def _set_time(time_tuple):
    import pywin32
    # http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api__SetSystemTime_meth.html
    # pywin32.SetSystemTime(year, month , dayOfWeek , day , hour , minute , second , millseconds )
    dayOfWeek = datetime.datetime(time_tuple).isocalendar()[2]
    pywin32.SetSystemTime( time_tuple[:2] + (dayOfWeek,) + time_tuple[2:])
```